# MVC Scaffolding error: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor, scaffolding

I followed the instruction in this [post](http://rachelappel.com/ready-set-scaffold-build-asp.net-mvc-3-applications-quickly-with-mvcscaffolding), but when I try to add a product I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Source Error: 


Line 63: </div>
Line 64: <div class="editor-field">
Line 65:     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, ((IEnumerable<GAM.Models.Category>)ViewBag.PossibleCategories).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
Line 66:         Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name), 
Line 67:         Value = option.Id.ToString(),
```

The controller code is:

```csharp
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.PossibleCategory = context.Categories;
    return View();
} 

//
// POST: /Product/Create

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Products.Add(product);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    ViewBag.PossibleCategory = context.Categories;
    return View(product);
}
```

And the code of the view is:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, ((IEnumerable<GAM.Models.Category>)ViewBag.PossibleCategories).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
    Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name), 
    Value = option.Id.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (option.Id == Model.CategoryId)
}), "Choose...")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is the following:

You assign this property within the `Controller`:

```
ViewBag.PossibleCategory = context.Categories;
```

Then, in your `View` you try to read this dynamic `ViewBag` property:

```
ViewBag.PossibleCategories
```

Can you see the error? You're giving different names... You do not get compile time checking because `ViewBag` uses the new C# 4 [`dynamic` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). `ViewBag.PossibleCategories` will only be resolved at runtime. As there's no `ViewBag` property that matches `ViewBag.PossibleCategories` you get this error: `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source`

To solve this just do this:

```
ViewBag.PossibleCategories = context.Categories;
```

Comment: Very nice catch!! I had the exact same problem and couldn't for my life see what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error in .NET 5 (.NET Core), with EF Core 5 and MVC.

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: connectionString
```

The problem was that I didn't have an appsettings.json file, and therefore didn't have the connectionstrings for the database, so the scaffolding could not connect to the database.